# How can this non-recursive quicksort be optimized to reduce stack usage（c language）

Tags: c

This is a non-recursive program to realize quicksort, and I use an array to simulate the implementation of the stack, but every time I sort a part of the array, the footprint increases exponentially. How to optimize this program to make the usage smaller? Like reusing the space that was previously discarded (where X has been traversed) or whatever, I really want to figure out, thank you in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int stack[1000];

int partion(int a[],int begin,int end)
{
    int l= begin;
    int r= end;
    int pole = a[begin];
    while(l<r)
    {
        while(l<r && a[r]>=pole)
            r--;
        if(l<r)
        {
            a[l] = a[r];
            l++;
        }
        while(l<r && a[l]<= pole)
            l++;
        if(l<r)
        {
            a[r] = a[l];
            r--;
        }
    }
    a[r]= pole;
    return r;
}

void nonRecursiveQuickSort(int a[], int begin, int end);
int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[10]={0,1,-3,4,2,6,-9,0,8,10};
    nonRecursiveQuickSort(a, 0, 10);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}

void nonRecursiveQuickSort(int a[], int begin, int end)
{
    int l = begin;
    int r = end;

    //replace the stack with an array, which stores the split boundaries
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    //add left boundary
    stack[y++] = l;
    //add right boundary
    stack[y++] = r;

    // If the left boundary is smaller than the right boundary, the data to be processed is indicated
    while (x < y)
    {
        // Simulate stack popout left boundary
        int left = stack[x++];
        //Simulate stack popout right boundary
        int right = stack[x++];
        // Call partition function 
        int pos = partion(a, left, right);
        //if Meet the conditions, repress the stack
        if (left < pos - 1)
        {
            stack[y++] = left;
            stack[y++] = pos - 1;
        }
        if (pos + 1 < right)
        {
            stack[y++] = pos + 1;
            stack[y++] = right;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You never pop anything from the stack....

Comment: I use x++ to stimulate the pop of stack,when x==y,all the element in the array which is used to stimulate the stack are poped out

Comment: @蒋浩楠 - Your data structure, although stored as an array named `stack`, is not a stack, but rather a FIFO; the data are stored in a sliding, variable sized array slice.

Answer (score 0):

The call `nonRecursiveQuickSort(a, 0, 10)` is wrong, since this causes a[10] to be referenced in `partion`; correct is `nonRecursiveQuickSort(a, 0, 9)`.

> reusing the space that was previously discarded (where X has been traversed)

To do that, the indexes `x` and `y` into the FIFO named `stack` are to wrap around at the end of the array. This amended version of your loop in `nonRecursiveQuickSort` does it, also with checks to prevent overrun:

```
    #define DIM sizeof stack / sizeof *stack    // DIM must be even
    while (x != y)
    {
        // Simulate stack popout left boundary
        int left = stack[x++];
        //Simulate stack popout right boundary
        int right = stack[x++];
        if (x == DIM) x = 0;    // wrap around
        // Call partition function 
        int pos = partion(a, left, right);
        //if Meet the conditions, repress the stack
        if (left < pos - 1)
        {
            stack[y++] = left;
            stack[y++] = pos - 1;
            if (y == DIM) y = 0;    // wrap around
            if (y == x) puts("FIFO full"), exit(1);
        }
        if (pos + 1 < right)
        {
            stack[y++] = pos + 1;
            stack[y++] = right;
            if (y == DIM) y = 0;    // wrap around
            if (y == x) puts("FIFO full"), exit(1);
        } 
    }
```